# remove .php extension with .htaccess for only one directory?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite url only one directory named `gallery`.
I would like to have `abc.com/photos/gallery/picture/` instead of `abc.com/photos/gallery/picture.php`

```
.htaccess
index.php
/photos
    /gallery 
        index.php
        picture.php
        functions.php
/videos
```

Here is my code to `.htaccess` but it doesn't work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/[.*]/?$ photos/gallery/$1.php#{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /gallery/foo.php to /gallery/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(/+gallery/[^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]

## To internally forward /gallery/foo to /gallery/foo.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(gallery/.*?)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Ow, it works great. Thank you @anubhava ! Except I had to change `gallery/` to `photos/gallery/`

Comment: @Steffi: You're welcome, somehow I overlooked the fact that it is `/photos/gallery' instead of `/gallery'